# Are today's Catholics encouraged to study the Bible at home?

Tags: bible, catholicism

How do Catholics view personal scripture study? Are members of the congregation encouraged to do any studying at home?

Comment: Welcome "user3726" -- this is actually a good, simple question. I wish I thought of it first. :P

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is yes:

> The Church “forcefully and specifically exhorts all the Christian
>   faithful... to learn ‘the surpassing knowledge of Jesus Christ,’ by
>   frequent reading of the divine Scriptures. ‘Ignorance of the
>   Scriptures is ignorance of Christ.’”

-- [Catechism of the Catholic Church, paragraph 133](http://www.usccb.org/beliefs-and-teachings/what-we-believe/catechism/catechism-of-the-catholic-church/epub/index.cfm?p=11-chapter2.xhtml%23para133)

The Church offers some strategies and practices for getting more out of scripture as well. One of note is [Lectio Divina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lectio_Divina), a pretty old approach in which you are encouraged to approach a passage like so:

1. **Read it.** A fairly obvious step. You read the selected passage.
2. **Meditate.** Ponder the Living Word, trusting the Holy Spirit to guide you.
3. **Pray.** Speak with God about the passage.
4. **Contemplate.** Sit in silent, loving attentiveness to the Word of God.